# Which hand wins at showdown?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy, reading-hands, hand

Board - `9963A`

Hand 1 - `36`

Hand 2 - `A8`

Which hand wins and why?

Answer (score 0):

`A8` wins as it has a best 5 card hand of `AA998` (2 pair - Aces and nines), whereas the `36` only has `9966A` (2 pair - Nines and sixes).